# Form processing with JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, forms, parameters, jquery-mobile, get

Process the data handed to an html page from a form.

This is my form:

```
  <form  data-theme="b"    method="get"    action="process.html"    enabled>           <fieldset>
 <div   data-role="fieldcontain"> 
 <label for="basic>  Name  </label>
 <input type="text" name="basic" id="basic" value=""   />                                   </div>                                
 <button type="submit" data-theme="b" name="submit"  value="submit-value">  Submit     </button>               
   </fieldset> 
</form>
```

So when it comes to process.html the values should be in the url, such as process.html?submit=submit. But I can't seem to be able to read them at all.

How should I go about doing the above successfully?

Comment: I think this could solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by adding this before `</head>` . Turns off all the AJAX that gets in the way of such a GET form.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
                            $.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled = false;
                            $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
                            $.mobile.ajaxFormsEnabled =false;
              });
```